# How to store Set<Set<String>> inside the SharePreferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am using `SharedPreference` in my project.

I know `sharedPreference` can store `Set<String>` by using `prefs.putStringSet()`.   But I have a situation where I need to store `Set<Set<String>>` in  `sharedPreference`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use **Gson** to convert `Set<Set<String>>` to string then save it in `sharepreference` , but there is no direct way to save this type in `sharepreference`

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonObject = gson.toJson(your_set_variable);

    editor.putString(KEY_PROJECTS, jsonObject );
    editor.commit();
```

***Updated :***
this is the Gson library from google if you need to use it , add it in your gradle dependencies

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
```

this library provided for you to convert any object you have to string and then convert this json string to your type you want , and stackoverflow and google had many and many of examples to using it

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer please. Detailed explanation will be of great help.

Comment: ok , sharedPreference using editor of course can store int, float, String, boolean, long, StringSet just , it means there is no other way to store any type except the previous types , so if you want to save any type like Set<Set<String>> or custom object for example you can't store it in shared preference unless you converte it to string using Gson library from google, i will update my answer to set these library in your project

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with SharedPreferences but you can save the set to a file.

```
FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
os.writeObject(set);
os.close();
fos.close();
```

EDIT: You can then load it like this.

```
FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(fileName);
ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
Set<Set<String>> set = (Set) is.readObject();
is.close();
fis.close();
```